# if i execute this program, Im getting "Failed to Free". But Inside FREE function, it was deallocate the memory properly only

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
typedef struct
{
    int a ;
    char b;
    char c[50];
}TEST;

void *allocate(int count,int  size);
void FREE(TEST *ptr);
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TEST *test = NULL ;
    void *ptr = NULL ;
    ptr = allocate(2,sizeof(TEST));
    test = (TEST *)ptr;
    test->a = 1;
    test->b = 'A';
    strcpy(test->c,"siva");

    FREE(test);
    if(test != NULL) //here Im getting issues, test remains pointing address
        printf("\n Failed to free");
    else
        printf("\n Free Success");
    return 0;
}
void *allocate(int count,int  size)
{
    void *ptr;
    ptr = calloc(count,size); // here allocated successfully
    return ptr;

}
void FREE(TEST *ptr)
{
    free(ptr);
    ptr = NULL ; // Deallocated Successfully
}
```

In this code, i just called one allocation function to allocate memory dynamically, after that i called FREE function to free that memory,  both functions working properly only. but inside main function after called the free function, why still test pointer pointing to the memory?

Comment: What did you expect and **why** do you think changing a local variable has external effect?

Comment: Also: do not use all-uppercase for functions. There are few standards in C for the case of identifiers, but all-uppercase == macro is well-accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the variable `ptr` inside the `FREE` function is a local variable, changing it will only change the local variable, nothing outside of the function will be modified.

What you need to do is to pass the variable *by reference*, which is not supported by C. C only have passing *by value*. But reference argument-passing can be *emulated* using pointers. So you need to pass a pointer to the pointer:

```
void FREE(TEST **ptr);
```

Call this using the address-of operator `&`:

```
FREE(&test);
```

and inside the function use the dereference operator `*` to access the original pointer variable.